# New Elastic Beanstalk application - instance profile associated with the environment does not exist" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to deploy my java project on AWS using beantalks service but I'm getting

```
"The instance profile "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role" associated with the environment does not exist."
```

error consistently. I checked all existing solutions but somehow I'm missing.

**What did I do?**

- Follow Elastic Beanstalk -> Create a new application

  - Type name for the application
- Create an environment

  - Type name for environment
  - Choose platform as Java
  - For "Service access" I used `Create and use new service role`
  - ...
- Submit Application

Then I got the error

```
"The instance profile "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role" associated with the environment does not exist."
```

I have already checked IAM roles to make sure `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` to make sure it has the required permissions.

IAM -> Roles -> "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role" have below permissions

- AmazonEC2FullAccess
- AmazonRDSFullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
- AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
- AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
- AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth
- AWSElasticBeanstalkCustomPlatformforEC2Role
- AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk

I know most of them are not needed but I ended up adding unnecessary permissions.
It should've been quite straightforward but I'm missing something.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please check this detailed answer to fix the error:- stackoverflow.com/a/76620598/12326605